# How to make distribution of predicted value similar to training example?

Tags: regression

Running regression analysis, for weak relationships, the predicted value tends to cluster around the mean.

Is there any method to force the distribution of the predicted value similar to the training example?

I know it will sacrifice the MSE.

Comment: Here is an animation page showing a curve fit, with 95% confidence intervals, of two completely unrelated random variables. The animation shows that as the number of data points increases, so does the statistical confidence that the fitted equation is equal to the mean value: http://zunzun.com/CommonProblems/RandomData_A.html

Comment: @James Philips, the answer should not go to comments.

Comment: @epo because my comment did not attempt to answer the question, I request that you please re-read the question.

Comment: You should provide some more information about your data and variables.